# Is it possible to use aptitude on a redhat machine?

Tags: redhat, apt, aptitude

We're having to manage a server for a client that is running RHEL 4.

Is it possible to run aptitude on this server to install/manage packages?

Comment: What's wrong with `yum`?

Comment: Just wanted to know if it is possible to use aptitude.

Answer (score 4):

rpmforge has apt and aptitude for RHEL5, it probably has also the package for EL4.

Comment: that's interesting! But aptitude and friends are designed to work with apt repositories. So I am wondering if this aptitude works together with the yum repositories.

Comment: it's just a replacement for you and under the hood will use yum repositories and rpm commands

Answer (score 1):

No. Red Hat-type distros use the rpm system for package management, with frontends such as yum and yast.

Debian-type distros use the dpkg system for package management, with better frontends like aptitude and apt-get.

If you want to use aptitude, you'll need to install Debian or Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

The package manager is the most fundamental part of a distribution, it is what makes a 'distribution' work.

I would not recommend using a different package manager with a distribution - I think the most reliable and safe thing to do is to become familiar with the package manager (and its front-ends) of choice on the distribution you're using.